# Why i cannot get 100 ether in pet-shop?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I have done 8 steps in pet-shop in Truffle:

8. In the box titled "New RPC URL" enter http://localhost:9545 and click Save.
9. The network name at the top will switch to say "Private Network".
   Click the left-pointing arrow next to "Settings" to close out of the page and return to the Accounts page.

Each account created by Truffle Develop is given 100 ether. You'll notice it's slightly less on the first account because some gas was used when the contract itself was deployed.

but i cannot find 100 ether in MetaMask, it is still 0 ether in account1.

Can you help me?

Comment: Connect to the localhost:9545 network through the network selection section at the top of the metamask extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct seed phrase entered in step 6: `In the box marked Wallet Seed, enter the mnemonic that was displayed when launching Truffle Develop:`

Answer (score 1):

You can see your correct balance by switching to the correct testnet. Click "Custom RPC" in MetaMask and enter `http://127.0.0.1:9545`.

The tutorial has been updated but still does have an error in it. http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

Make sure to not include `view` int eh adopt function in contracts/Adoption.sol for it to work with MetaMask.